# js искажает ссылку

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Есть [статическая страничка](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/q11/) с двумя ссылками. На страничке используется популярный скрипт `fancybox`. По первой ссылке видео не открывается, по второй - открывается. В исходнике страницы обе ссылки рабочие. При клике не первую ссылку в консоли появляется ошибка с искажённым адресом

Answer (score 1):

Вы когда вызываете FancyBox, сами меняете ссылку по RegExp'у. Смотрите внимательно параметры вызова FancyBox, там есть строчка:

```
'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
```

Comment: я с этой строчкой что только не делал. не влияет она никак

Comment: Очень даже влияет. Закомментируйте её на фиг.

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin , Вы специально используете ссылки на youtube разной длины?

Comment: пробовал и закомментировать, и без реплейса использовать, и многое другое. правда не влияет. кэш сбрасывал. в браузере, в цмф

ссылки разной длины использую без умысла. первая это ссылка заказчика. вторую взял первую попавшуюся для примера

Comment: Судя по тому, что конечная ссылка имеет вместо watch?v= v/, регулярное выражение срабатывает, значит оно является проблемой.

Comment: здесь http://www.test1.ru/site_surma/q12/ я исключил действие регулярного выражения. не заработало, как видите

Comment: Ваш последний пример не открывается